# Attribute that instructs standart string template to display string as plain HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, razor

For displaying/editing forms I use `Html.DisplayForModel()`. Whether there is native ASP.NET MVC attribute that can instruct standart string template to display model property with type of string as plain html, or I need to create my own attribute and change standart string template to apply this behavior?
I don't want to crush `Html.DisplayForModel()` expression and use `Html.Raw()`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateCreated)
@Html.Raw(Model.Comment)

public class MyModel
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Title {get;set;}
public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
public string Comment {get;set;} // contains plain html
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a special display template for this property `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Unencoded.cshtml`:

```
@model string
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

and then in your view model use the [`[UIHint]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Unencoded")]
    public string Comment { get; set; } // contains plain html
}
```

Now your main view could simply look like this:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

By using the `Html.Raw` helper you certify that you fully realize the consequences of this and that your site becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks and that you take adequate actions to avoid them.

Comment: It is safe solution for me, because i use wiki-syntax for typed text formatting and html encode before pass data to database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the display template of comments (place view into DisplayTemplates folder)

//sample comments.cshtml

```
@model MyApplicationNamespace.ViewModels.Comments

<ul>

@if (Model != null)
{
   for (int i =0; i<Model.Count(); i++ )
       {
           <li>Model.UserName + ":" + Model.CommentText </li>
       }
}

</ul>
```

And from now on, your comment will be rendered with this template. If you use built in autogenerating templates with `@Html.DisplayForModel()`, the properties of `Comment` type will be automatically rendered with this template, otherwise, use `DisplayFor` as with id, title, dateCreated cases

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Comments)
```

Html.DisplayFor return `MvcHtmlString`, and it is not html encoded any more

Comment: May be I misled you by my misprinted plural form of 'Comments'. I mean Comment (text), that have type of string.